# Single Post Breadcrumb not linking back to Custom Post Type Index?

Tags: templates

I am using a breadcrumb code that will not place a link on two custom single post pages linking back to two custom post type index pages. The full Breadcrumb code can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/xNwXxWv6

```
if(get_post_type() == 'Portfolio'){
 echo '<a href="' . 'http://www.mysite.com/web-portfolio'  . '">' .  'Portfolio'. '</a>' . $markup;

} else if(get_post_type() == 'Artwork'){
 echo '<a href="' . 'http://www.mysite.com/art-portfolio'  . '">' . 'Artwork' .  '</a>' . $markup;
}
```

EDIT: This has been resolved with the code above, thanks all who helped.

Comment: `if( !$type == 'portfolio')` is confusing. Do you mean `if( $type != 'portfolio')`? If that's the case, it will help those who answer get a better grip on your logic. `!$type` looks like a mistake to me at first glance.

Comment: What do you mean by linking to a "single.php template"? You don't link to *template files*, but rather to *posts*. WordPress determines the appropriate template file to use to render the current query. Also: please post the rendered output of that code, and explain what you *expected* that output to be.

Comment: Let me try to rephrase my question: what link are you *trying* to display there? I *assume* you're trying to display a link either to a single post of a custom post type, or else the archive index page for that custom post type?

Comment: Also, looking at your pastebin: it looks like you're missing a closing brace on lines 66-68, to correspond to the `if` statement opening brace on line 63. If so, this question is simply a PHP syntax error, and not WordPress-related.

Comment: `if( $type != 'Portfolio') {` Why `!=` and not `==` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/is_single) you will see that `is_single` accepts post id's / titles / slugs and

**EDIT**
If you are using two custom post types then WP will select the right `single-POSTNAME.php` And in your check you best check the posttype like:

```
if ( get_post_type() == 'postfolio' ) { /*do stuff*/ }
```

Comment: I failed to see it does not except templates. I've been reading the codex for a year but it's logic often fails me. Even using the slug, id, or title produces no effect still shows one or the other. Help?

Comment: @Zoa See my update

Comment: The echo provided above seems correct, if you made changes to your code update your answer.

Comment: I've updated my code will you take a look?

Comment: your { and } are all screwed up you should be getting PHP errors fix that first If you don't see errors turn on WP_DEBUG

Comment: I am unable to find any errors using WP_Debug and Syntax Checker, only two notices that directly involve the bit of code I need help with and have coded improperly. I updated Pastebin and the OP to reflect that. Thanks again for looking at it

Comment: Hi, Janw I edited my code today and was wondering if you could take a look at it and instruct me on why it is not working? Just to refresh I am trying to add a link to two single post pages leading back to two custom post type index pages. Thanks.

Comment: on line you check if the post type is `post` **inside** that check you check if the posttype is artwork/portfolio. That will never trigger if it already **has** been checked for `post` post-type

Answer (score 2):

Referring to the template heirarchy here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

[image]

We can see your choices out of the box are:

- single.php
- single-post.php
- single-{post type}.php

But judging from your problem, I would recommend against using multiple templates.

Instead define via post meta/custom fields wether it is a portfolio or an art piece. You can add a checkbox or radio buttons in the backend to control this, or just manually set it.

```
$url = '<a href="">artwork url</a>';
$type = get_post_meta($post->ID,'zoa_post_type',true);
if($type == 'portfolio'){
    $url = '<a href="">portfolio url</a>';
}
```

Also, [`is_single`](http://queryposts.com/function/is_single/) doesn't take a template name.

***Edit***

It would appear you neglected to mention you are using 2 different custom post types.

In that case:

```
if(get_post_type() == 'Portfolio'){
    echo '<a href="' . 'http://www.mysite.com/web-portfolio'  . '">' . 'Portfolio' .  '</a>';
} else if(get_post_type() == 'Artwork'){
    echo '<a href="' . 'http://www.mysite.com/art-portfolio'  . '">' . 'Artwork' .  '</a>';
}
echo $markup;
```

Comment: Comments purged. This is not appropriate use of them, we have chat rooms (private if necessary) for that.